# wpdb query problem to access previous 3 days posts

Tags: query, wpdb, sql

I am trying to get all published posts titles by author id 2 most recent by post date for the last days. Here is my query:

```
"SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_author = 2 ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 3 "
```

This displays most recent 3 posts instead posts of last 3 days.
How to get that query right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for the last three posts ordered by post date, not for the posts from the last three days-- `ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 3`. [`post_date` has a time component to it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts). It is not just marked with a date. Even so, that `LIMIT` would restrict the query to last three in the list, not all of the posts that are more recent than three days.

What you need is something like this:

```
SELECT post_title 
FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_author = 2 
AND post_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 day)
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

See the following for other options and caveats: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96562/21376